# Understanding vagrant and virtual hosts (403 forbidden)

Tags: apache, shell, vagrant, virtualhost

I am currently learning, and being in full battle with vagrant :(
(working on mac, with virtualbox)

**Let me explain**
For my web projects, I have this tree:

/Users/noos/projects

- project1
- project2
- tools

  - box

*Project1* folder is my first project.
*Project2* folder is my second project.
In *tools > box* folder, here is my vagrant box, with 2 files:

**Vagrantfile:**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

    # Mount shared folder using NFS
    config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/noos/projects", "/vagrant",
        id: "core",
        :nfs => true,
        :mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']


    #config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant",
        #id: "core",
        #:nfs => true,
        #:mount_options => ['nolock,vers=3,udp,noatime']

    # Do some network configuration
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.100.100"

    # Assign a quarter of host memory and all available CPU's to VM
    # Depending on host OS this has to be done differently.
    config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
        host = RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os']

        if host =~ /darwin/
            cpus = `sysctl -n hw.ncpu`.to_i
            mem = `sysctl -n hw.memsize`.to_i / 1024 / 1024 / 4

        elsif host =~ /linux/
            cpus = `nproc`.to_i
            mem = `grep 'MemTotal' /proc/meminfo | sed -e 's/MemTotal://' -e 's/ kB//'`.to_i / 1024 / 4

        # Windows...
        else
            cpus = 4
            mem = 2048
        end

        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", mem]
        vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", cpus]
    end

    config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"

end
```

**bootstrap.sh:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Update () {
    echo "-- Update packages --"
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get upgrade
}
Update

echo "-- Prepare configuration for MySQL --"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password root"
sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password root"

echo "-- Install tools and helpers --"
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes python-software-properties vim htop curl git npm

echo "-- Install PPA's --"
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/redis-server
Update

echo "-- Install NodeJS --"
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -

echo "-- Install packages --"
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes apache2 mysql-server-5.6 git-core nodejs rabbitmq-server redis-server
sudo apt-get install -y --force-yes php7.0-common php7.0-dev php7.0-json php7.0-opcache php7.0-cli libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-mysql php7.0-fpm php7.0-curl php7.0-gd php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-mbstring php7.0-bcmath php7.0-zip
Update

echo "-- Configure PHP &Apache --"
sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = E_ALL/" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
sed -i "s/display_errors = .*/display_errors = On/" /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini
sudo a2enmod rewrite

echo "-- Creating virtual hosts --"
sudo ln -fs /vagrant/public/ /var/www/app
cat << EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf
<Directory "/var/www/">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/app
    ServerName app.dev
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin
    ServerName phpmyadmin.dev
</VirtualHost>

EOF
sudo a2ensite default.conf

echo "-- Restart Apache --"
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

echo "-- Install Composer --"
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

echo "-- Install phpMyAdmin --"
wget -k https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/4.0.10.11/phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.11-english.tar.gz
sudo tar -xzvf phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.11-english.tar.gz -C /var/www/
sudo rm phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.11-english.tar.gz
sudo mv /var/www/phpMyAdmin-4.0.10.11-english/ /var/www/phpmyadmin

echo "-- Setup databases --"
mysql -uroot -proot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root' WITH GRANT OPTION; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;"
mysql -uroot -proot -e "CREATE DATABASE my_database";
```

What I want now is to be able to have virtual host for my different projects.So I edited the file /etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf to put this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /vagrant/project1/web
    ServerName local.project1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /vagrant/project2/web
    ServerName local.project2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, if I try to access one of my pages, I run into a "403 forbidden error page".

As I said before, I am currently in full "self training" with vagrant, therefore I am not sure to understand why this error.

Help and / or explanations would be welcome.
In advance a big thank you!

Comment: You're not sharing the `projects` folder with your VM

Comment: @FrédéricHenri, I'm not sure I understand. Could you give me some explanations please?
Thank you!